# Dividing Tuple Values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

How do I divide the following tuple values, based on their keys? I have the following below:

```
numerator_list = [('Sam', 10), ('Alex', 8), ('Tom', 12)]
denominator_list = [('Alex', 2), ('Tom', 3), ('Sam',5)]
```

I want to divide the values of the numerator_list by the values of the denominator_list ***based on the common key names***.
For demonstration purpose, I want the output to be the following below:

```
my_output = [('Sam', 2), ('Alex', 4), ('Tom', 4)]
```

Comment: This won't happen without any code. [ask]

Comment: No crap, this is why I posted the question

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your list of tuples of 2 elements to a dictionary and use `set` intersection to keep the common keys:

```
num = dict(numerator_list)
den = dict(denominator_list)

my_output = {}
for key in set(num).intersection(den):
    if den[key] != 0  # avoid ZeroDivisionError
        my_output[key] = num[key] / den[key]
```

Output:

```
>>> my_output
{'Sam': 2.0, 'Alex': 4.0, 'Tom': 4.0}
```

With a dict comprehension:

```
my_output = {key: num[key] / den[key] for key in set(num).intersection(den) if den[key] != 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
numerator_list = [('Sam', 10), ('Alex', 8), ('Tom', 12)]
denominator_list = [('Alex', 2), ('Tom', 3), ('Sam',5)]
d = dict(denominator_list)
c = [(name, t/d[name]) for name, t in numerator_list]
```